# What are the reasons for using hydraulic power on major aircraft systems?

Tags: aircraft-systems, hydraulic-system

What are the actual benefits or advantages of using Hydraulic energy in aircraft systems, compared to pneumatic and electrical systems.

Comment: It's very compact.

Comment: This is a broad question, I'm sure whole books could be written on this subject.

Comment: Just imagine using an electric motor on an excavator. It's possible, but more complex. Hydraulic is powerful, we just need a small jack to move a huge mass.

Comment: Hydraulics don't compress so more positive displacement. Hydraulics run at high pressure so smaller actuators can be used. Hydraulic leaks are visible. Pneumatic leaks aren't.

Comment: A comparison with electric motors/actuators can be seen in this thread: [Why do most commercial airplanes use hydraulics instead of electric/servo motors?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24146/why-do-most-commercial-airplanes-use-hydraulics-instead-of-electric-servo-motors?noredirect=1&lq=1)